# certbot letsencrypt certificate installation failed

Tags: debian, nginx, letsencrypt, certbot

I have a small test server at home and I registered with letsencrypt to get a valid certificate.

Certificate expired and wasn't automatically renewed (no harm done, this is strictly for testing purposes).

I don't remember exactly how I installed the certificate and "certbot" was not installed on my server (actually a LXD container, if relevant) running "Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)".

I installed `certbot` with standard:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx
```

and then proceeded to use it:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d blog.mydomain.it
```

but I got an unexpected error:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Requesting a certificate for blog.mydomain.it

Successfully received certificate.
Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.mydomain.it/fullchain.pem
Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.mydomain.it/privkey.pem
This certificate expires on 2024-02-14.
These files will be updated when the certificate renews.
Certbot has set up a scheduled task to automatically renew this certificate in the background.

Deploying certificate
Successfully deployed certificate for blog.mydomain.it to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog.conf
We were unable to install your certificate, however, we successfully restored your server to its prior configuration.

NEXT STEPS:
- The certificate was saved, but could not be installed (installer: nginx). After fixing the error shown below, try installing it again by running:
  certbot install --cert-name blog.mydomain.it

nginx restart failed:
2023/11/16 23:31:55 [emerg] 561#561: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey("/etc/letsencrypt/blog.mydomain.it_ecc/private.key") failed (SSL: error:05800074:x509 certificate routines::key values mismatch)

Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

I guess there's some mismatch between previous certificate install and what `certbot` is trying to do, but I am at a loss about how to proceed.

I have no problem in wiping the old certificate, if that's useful, but I would like to understand  before I make a deeper mess.

I need to reinstall certificates without disturbing the server itself (reasonable downtime is perfectly OK).

### UPDATE:

As requested (it doesn't seem to add any info, but...):

```
mcon@webserver:~$ sudo certbot install --cert-name blog.mydomain.it
[sudo] password for mcon: 
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Deploying certificate
Successfully deployed certificate for blog.mydomain.it to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog.conf
We were unable to install your certificate, however, we successfully restored your server to its prior configuration.
nginx restart failed:
2023/11/17 09:08:38 [emerg] 3162#3162: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey("/etc/letsencrypt/blog.mydomain.it_ecc/private.key") failed (SSL: error:05800074:x509 certificate routines::key values mismatch)

Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
mcon@webserver:~$
```

### UPDATE2:

my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog.conf` contained the following definition:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name blog.mydomain.it;
    root /var/www/vitepress;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/blog.mydomain.it/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/blog.mydomain.it/privkey.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/blog.mydomain.it/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/blog.mydomain.it_ecc/private.key;

    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

commenting out the second `ssl_certificate`/`ssl_certificate_key`
pair actually solves the problem.

Now my my (working!) installation reads:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name blog.mydomain.it;
    root /var/www/vitepress;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.mydomain.it/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.mydomain.it/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
server {
    if ($host = blog.mydomain.it) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name blog.mydomain.it;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I am still curious about what was actually wrong and why those two lines were there (to avoid repeating the mistake, of course) but problem seems resolved.

Comment: You didn't show us output from when you tried following the `certbot install --cert-name blog.mydomain.it` advice.

Comment: @J_H: I added requested info, but it doesn't seem to add anything to the previous run.

Comment: Add relevant parts of `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog.conf` and `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log` to the post, please.